# Compound natural key in DbSet.AddOrUpdate

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to use the CodeFirst data migrations in EF5 with a table that has a composite natural key.  Is it possible to specify this in the first argument to DbSet.AddOrUpdate, like

```
context.Table1.AddOrUpdate(
     t=>t.Column1 && t.Column2,
     new Table1 { properties... }
);
```

How would one specify using more than one property in this case?

Thanks,
Matthew

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Turns out I had to use an anonymous type in the first argument, e.g.

```
t => new { t.Column1, t.Column2 }
```

Comment: If one of those columns is a nullable type you've got issues